# How to build a 3D matrix from 1D time series in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have four `(N,)` vectors `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`:

```py
import numpy as np

N = 100

A = 1*np.ones(N)   # => array([1,1,1,...])
B = 2*np.ones(N)   # => array([2,2,2,...])
C = 3*np.ones(N)   # => array([3,3,3,...])
D = 4*np.ones(N)   # => array([4,4,4,...])
```

In my application, these are each an element of a matrix and the matrix varies over time (although in this example each is constant in time). I want a matrix with shape `(N,2,2)` such that I have a 2x2 matrix for each time step, like `[[a,b],[c,d]]`, extended along axis 0. Is there a nicer way to stack these into that kind of shape than what I have below?

My solution:

```py
A_ = np.reshape(A, (N,1,1))
B_ = np.reshape(B, (N,1,1))
C_ = np.reshape(C, (N,1,1))
D_ = np.reshape(D, (N,1,1))

AB = np.concatenate((A_, B_),axis=2)
CD = np.concatenate((C_, D_),axis=2)

ABCD = np.concatenate((AB,CD),axis=1)
```

This gives:

```
>>> ABCD
array([[[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.]],

       [[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.]],

       [[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.]],
...
...
       [[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.]],

       [[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.]]])
```

As desired. It's just difficult to understand what it's doing, so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate as a 3D intermediate with [`dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html), then you'll be in the ideal order to perform a simple [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
np.dstack([A, B, C, D]).reshape(N, 2, 2)
```

Output:

```
array([[[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.]],

       [[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.]],

       [[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.]],

       ...,

       [[3., 4.],
        [3., 4.]]])
```

Intermediate:

```
np.dstack([A,B,C,D]).shape
# (1, 100, 4)
```

Comment: That's a neat solution. Could you add an explanation and I'll mark as accepted?

Comment: Not sure what is unclear, I added some details. Let me know if you have a specific question ;)

Comment: That's great, just for those of us who aren't as familiar with dstack and numpy stacking in general